# How can I get the error message into my Go program using Go's os/exec library?

Tags: go

I am running code that executes "psql". It should return some error code, because the database is not up.

It should return

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory    Is the server running locally and accepting     connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

However it returning the standard error of

```
2013/11/21 15:06:19 exit status 2
exit status 1
```

Here is the code

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os/exec"

)

func main() {
        out, err := exec.Command("psql").Output()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n",out)
}
```

Comment: You might want to use a Postgres client library like [pq](https://github.com/bmizerany/pq) instead of running psql.

Comment: That is true, but I just used psql as an example.  The point is I want to be able to print out the stderr.

Comment: Makes sense! Just thought the pointer to pq might help.

Answer (score 2):

Because output only returns data from the STDOUT, while the psql error is printing that data on the STDERR stream

You need to read the STDERR:

```
func (c *Cmd) StderrPipe() (io.ReadCloser, error)
```

Comment: I think you meant STDOUT instead of STDIN